Is there any way to sequentially render video widgets in GTK4 without causing memory leaks?
When trying to render one video after the other in a circular queue, I'm getting significant memory leaks for some reason.
What would be the best way to make a simple repeating video carousel GUI without causing any leak in memory? Removing references doesn't seem to do much either, I just hope it isn't caused within Gstreamer itself.
I tried g_object_unref when wanting to delete the widgets from the main window, without success. The memory just keeps piling on.
Edit: Here's a very minimal program to demonstrate the issue. This switches between two video files every 5 seconds, but still somehow uses up all of my available memory.
static gboolean switch_video(gpointer user_data)
{
    static bool toggle = false;
    GtkVideo *video = GTK_VIDEO(user_data);

    std::string path = toggle ? "files/video1.mp4" : "files/video2.mp4";
    GtkMediaStream *new_media_file = gtk_media_file_new_for_filename(path.c_str());

    gtk_video_set_media_stream(video, GTK_MEDIA_STREAM(new_media_file));
    gtk_media_stream_play(new_media_file);
    g_object_unref(new_media_file);

    toggle = !toggle;
    return TRUE;
}

static void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new(app);

    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GTK4 Video Player");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 800, 600);

    GtkWidget *video = gtk_video_new();
    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), video);
    gtk_widget_show(window);

    g_timeout_add_seconds(5, switch_video, video);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
    int status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);

    return status;
}


Where is the minimal example showing this behaviour? Most likely you missed to drop a reference to some object that prevents removing a bigger pile.

Thank you for the help! I added an example that causes the issue, are there references I am forgetting? Wouldn't just changing the media stream for the video widget at each iteration work? @FlorianZwoch

The code looks fine to me. I see the same. Also using gtk_video_set_filename() I can produce a "too many open files" error. I suspect a bug in GStreameror or GTK.

I think you might be right. I tried with Holger's gtk_video_set_file implementation but I still get memory leaks. I'll try with GTK3 to see if I get the same issues, the whole point of using GTK4 was for the performance boost though so that kinda hurts.

I'm unsure about the GtkVideo implementation. Using GStreamer with gtk4paintable sink instead may behave differently.

The problem seems to be that the video, which was launched with GtkVideo, cannot be unloaded or stopped. "If you are writing a full-fledged video player, you may want to use the GdkPaintable API and a media framework such as Gstreamer directly."As it says in the documentation.  Sorry

Interesting, it seems odd that you couldn't free resources from a GTKVideo widget, but oh well. I'll see if I can achieve better results with GtkPaintable. Thanks for the help!
